# Device Activity Report Extension Crashed when adding 3 or more reports on one screen

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, wwdc, screen-time

Activity Report Extension crashes when adding 3 or more reports on one screen.

I'm trying to use the new Screen Time API from WWDC 2021 and 2022

I'm trying to show 3 reports on one screen, I created a simple SwiftUI app to demonstrate the issue where just a Text for each report is displayed. They all appear for a few seconds and then disappear with an error in the debug console. Our project is stuck because having 1 device activity report for all elements results in poor performance. The whole API seems laggy, but I'm wondering if it's an issue on my side or Apple's bug.

Screen Recording

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DniOo4QN5bY56sddZJvLTKtkGLQugXRi/view?usp=share_link

I'm getting the following error in the Xcode debug console

```
2023-09-02 22:36:37.763861-0400 TestApp3[6222:368344] [default] VS terminated with error: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted}
```

All targets and the project have Deployment Target iOS 16, I'm using XCode 14.3.1, and testing on iPhone 11 iOS 16.6

**ContentView.swift**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            DeviceActivityReport(.init("Total Activity1"))
            Spacer(minLength: 16)
            DeviceActivityReport(.init("Total Activity2"))
            Spacer(minLength: 16)
            DeviceActivityReport(.init("Total Activity3"))
        }
    }
}
```

**ActivityReport.swift**

```
@main
struct ActivityReport: DeviceActivityReportExtension {
    var body: some DeviceActivityReportScene {
        TotalActivityReport1 { totalActivity in
                .init(totalActivity: totalActivity)
        }
        TotalActivityReport2 { totalActivity in
            .init(totalActivity: totalActivity)
        }
        TotalActivityReport3 { totalActivity in
            .init(totalActivity: totalActivity)
        }
    }
}
```

**TotalActivityReport.swift**

```
extension DeviceActivityReport.Context {
    static let totalActivity1 = Self("Total Activity1")
    static let totalActivity2 = Self("Total Activity2")
    static let totalActivity3 = Self("Total Activity3")
}

struct TotalActivityReport1: DeviceActivityReportScene {
    let context: DeviceActivityReport.Context = .totalActivity1
    let content: (String) -> TotalActivityView1
    
    func makeConfiguration(representing data: DeviceActivityResults<DeviceActivityData>) async -> String {
        "Test1"
    }
}

struct TotalActivityReport2: DeviceActivityReportScene {
    let context: DeviceActivityReport.Context = .totalActivity2
    let content: (String) -> TotalActivityView2
    
    func makeConfiguration(representing data: DeviceActivityResults<DeviceActivityData>) async -> String {
        "Test2"
    }
}

struct TotalActivityReport3: DeviceActivityReportScene {
    let context: DeviceActivityReport.Context = .totalActivity3
    let content: (String) -> TotalActivityView3
    
    func makeConfiguration(representing data: DeviceActivityResults<DeviceActivityData>) async -> String {
        "Test3"
    }
}
```

**TotalActivityView.swift**

```
struct TotalActivityView1: View {
    let totalActivity: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(totalActivity)
    }
}

struct TotalActivityView2: View {
    let totalActivity: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(totalActivity)
    }
}

struct TotalActivityView3: View {
    let totalActivity: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(totalActivity)
    }
}
```